# Understanding SDL frame animation

Tags: c++, sdl, sdl-2

I am working through the book [SDL game development](https://www.packtpub.com/sites/default/files/9781849696821_Chapter_05.pdf). In the first project, there is a bit of code meant to move the coords of the rendered frame of a sprite sheet:

```
void Game::update()
{
    m_sourceRectangle.x = 128 * int((SDL_GetTicks()/100)%6);
}
```

I am having trouble understanding this... I know that it moves `m_sourceRectangle` 128 pixels along the x axis every 100 ms... but how does it actually work? Can somebody breakdown each element of this code to help me understand?

I don't understand why `SDL_GetTicks()` needs to be called to do this...

I also know that `%6` is there because there are 6 frames in the animation... but how does it actually do that?

The book says:

> Here we have used `SDL_GetTicks()` to find out the amount of milliseconds since SDL was initialized. We then divide this by the amount of time (in ms) we want between frames and then use the modulo operator to keep
>   it in range of the amount of frames we have in our animation. This code will (every 100 milliseconds) shift the x value of our source rectangle by
>   128 pixels (the width of a frame), multiplied by the current frame we want, giving us the correct position. Build the project and you should see the animation displayed.

But I am not sure I understand why getting the amount of milliseconds since SDL was initialized works.

Answer (score 3):

The modulo operator takes the rest of a division. So for example if GetTicks()  is 2600, first dividing by 100 makes it 26 and modulo 6 of 26 is 2. Therefore it's frame 2.

if GetTicks() is 3300; you divide by 100 and get 33; modulo 6 of 33 is 3; frame 3.

Comment: thanks for the answer.. that helps me understand what the modulo is there for... but what about multiplying GetTicks() by the number of miliseconds we want a frame to be onscreen? how does multiplying ticks by a number mean that that's how long it will be on screen?

Comment: a tick is basicly a cycle in a program. It's a kind of measurement of how long the program have been running. Multiplying with the number of milliseconds you want it to be doesn't work. 

Instead you could increase the number you are deviding with.

Comment: Sorry, I meant dividing... why does dividing the number of milliseconds get it to change at that time?

Answer (score 1):

Each frame will be displayed for 100ms, so at T=0ms it's Frame 0, t=100ms it's Frame `100/100`, at T=200ms it's Frame `200/100` and so on. So at T=`SDL_GetTicks()` ms, it's Frame `SDL_GetTicks()/100`. But than you only have 6 frames all together and cycling, therefore at T=`SDL_GetTicks()` ms it's in face Frame `(SDL_GetTicks()/100) % 6`.

There is an assumption here is that when the program start, Frame 0 is displayed, which may not be true because there are lots of things to do at starting which take time. But for simple demo to illustrate cycling of frames, it is good enough.

Hope this helps.